# How to read / rewrite text file in vb.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have an XML file like this

```
<serverlist>
      <server>
        <id>1</id>
        <ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
        <port>11101</port>
        <category sort="1">PVE</category>
        <name raw_name="TEST">
            <![CDATA[TEST]]>
        </name>
```

I want to read / rewrite the `127.0.0.1` Only and put it in a text box or from the text box to the file.

Comment: It seems an XML. Is it? In that case it can be way more simple

Comment: If you post a valid XML snippet you are more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an XML, so you can use LinQ to XML.

To get the value:

```
Private Function getValue(name As String) As String
    Dim doc = XDocument.Load("YourFilePath")
    Dim data = (From c In doc.Descendants(name)
                        Select c).First()
    Return data.Value
End Function
```

To set the value:

```
Private Sub setValue(name As String, value As String)
    Dim doc = XDocument.Load("YourFilePath")
    Dim data = (From c In doc.Descendants(name)
                        Select c).First()
    data.ReplaceAll(value)
    doc.Save("YourFilePath")
End Sub
```